# Does pagerank account for the semantics of inbound links?

Tags: algorithm, pagerank

Given what's known publicly about Google's PageRank algorithm, does PageRank account for the semantics of inbound links? That is, can PageRank tell the difference between a link that discusses the target positively or negatively and weight the results accordingly?

Comment: I don't think so; it would imply reading and understanding whole paragraphs written in many different languages, sometimes unclear and often with grammar mistakes. This task is way too difficult for computers as for today. But I have no references whatsoever, so this is more like a comment expressing my opinion rather than a satisfying answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it just considers links between pages.
Original paper here: http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/422/1/1999-66.pdf